# How to install omniORB on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, python, visual-c++

I installed Python 2.7 and MinGW, added everything which is needed to PATH (g++ and python), and downloaded omniORB from http://sourceforge.net/projects/omniorb/files/omniORB/omniORB-4.1.6/omniORB-4.1.6.tar.bz2/download, unzipped it.

I `cded` to omniORB directory but there were no omniORB binaries in \bin\x86_win32 directory.

So I have 2 questions:

1) where can I get omniORB binaries? (I would like to install omniORB on my computer with Windows XP/Vista/7 (both x86))

2) is it possible to install omniORB from source when I have only MinGW installed (no Visual C++)? How to do this (I need simple steps)? Thanks :)

Comment: You can get the free [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads). Since it is the compiler supported by the project on Windows, I am sure it will be much easier to compile *omniORB* from source using it.